# PHP: Convert array values from text to icon with HTML replacement through PHP or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I'm working on a project with WordPress + WooCommerce where I'm displaying custom WooCommerce attributes on the 'shop' page underneath a product title.

One of these attributes is called attr_icons. Some of the values associated with this attribute are: icon_new and icon_vegan. The intent is to transform these attributes from the original 'icon_new' into a HTML img tag. **The question: how do I convert these pieces of text into the HTML img tags?** My first PHP and Javascript/jQuery replacements have been unsuccessful...

The functional code used to display the clean icon attribute values:

```
function show_attr() {
    global $product;
    $attr_icons = array_values(wc_get_product_terms( $product_id, 'pa_icons'));
    echo implode(' ',$attr_icons);
}
```

This code has been saved in a child theme's functions.php.

HTML result of this code:

```
<h2 class="woocommerce-loop-product__title">TITLE</h2>
icon_focus icon_new icon_sc icon_trvl icon_vegan icon_wf
<table class="shop_attributes">
```

How to get from icon_new to `/icons/new.png` as image `src`:

```
<img src="/icons/new.png" alt="New" class="new" />
```

Through (preferably) PHP or (alternatively) javascript (+jQuery).

Comment: replace the implode with a foreach loop which generates the relevant HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just about there. I'd recommend a `foreach` here, where you can go through each result you get from WordPress, get the piece of the name you need through `str_replace()` and format the result into the `<img>` tag you want.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
function show_attr() {
    global $product;

    // Your WP results
    //$attr_icons = array_values( wc_get_product_terms( $product_id, 'pa_icons' ) );

    // My test data
    $attr_icons = array('icon_focus','icon_new','icon_sc','icon_trvl','icon_vegan','icon_wf');

    foreach($attr_icons as $attr_icon){
        $filename = str_replace('icon_','',$attr_icon);
        echo '<img src="/icons/'.$filename.'.png" alt="'.$filename.'" class="'.$filename.'">';
    }
}
```

Obviously, you'll want to remove my values for `$attr_icons` and use the results of `wc_get_product_terms` like you currently have.

With the code above, you should get this when you call `show_attr()`:

```
<img src="/icons/focus.png" alt="focus" class="focus">
<img src="/icons/new.png" alt="new" class="new">
<img src="/icons/sc.png" alt="sc" class="sc">
<img src="/icons/trvl.png" alt="trvl" class="trvl">
<img src="/icons/vegan.png" alt="vegan" class="vegan">
<img src="/icons/wf.png" alt="wf" class="wf">
```

Does that help at all?

Comment: Thanks Daniel. That was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

You can build a translation array and then search and replace using that:

```
$xlate = array('icon_new'   => '<img src="/icons/new.png" alt="New" class="new" />',
               'icon_vegan' => '<img src="/icons/vegan.png" alt="Vegan" class="vegan" />');
                //etc

$attr_icons = array_values(wc_get_product_terms($product_id, 'pa_icons'));
$attr_icons = str_replace(array_keys($xlate), $xlate, $attr_icons);
echo implode(' ', $attr_icons);
```

I don't know WordPress so no sure why you need the `array_values`...